# Opening TTStyledLabel images in ImageViewer

Tags: ios, three20, ttstyledtextlabel

Is there any way for me to make it so when a user clicks on an image that is in a TTStyledLabel it opens up in three20's image viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically yes. Since TTStyledText can contain html tags you can harness the three20 navigation to you your advantage, all you have to do is wrap the img tag with a  tag and set your own mapping for a controller that derives from three20's photo viewer.

```
NSString* kText = @"This is a test of styled labels. <a href=\"yourapp://photo/http%3A%2F%2Fsomeserver.com%2Fsmiley.png\"><img src=\"http://someserver.com/smiley.png\"/</a>";
TTStyledTextLabel* label1 = [[[TTStyledTextLabel alloc] init] autorelease];
label1.text = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:kText lineBreaks:YES URLs:YES];
```

in your app delegate have a mapping for your controller like this:

```
TTNavigator* navigator = [TTNavigator navigator];
TTURLMap* map = navigator.URLMap;
[map from:@"yourapp://photoViewer/(initWithPhotoUrl:)" toViewController:[TTWebController class]];
```

the the photo view controller should have this init method:

```
-(id)initWithPhotoUrl:(NSString*)photoURL {
    self = [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        NSString *unencodedURL = [photoURL gtm_stringByUnescapingFromURLArgument];//this is where you decode the string (notice we encode it in the html). Google toolbox has a nice category for Strings to encode and decode urls see: http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BURLArguments.h?r=373
    }
    return self;
}
```

Inside that initWithPhotoUrl: you need to create a photosource - please refer to the TTCatalog sample for a sample on how to create a MockPhotoSource.